# How to get full IDL for a Solana program?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, idl

I am facing difficulties in getting Interface Definition Language (IDL) for a program on Solana. I need the complete IDL for the following program: https://solscan.io/account/ArAA6CZC123yMJLUe4uisBEgvfuw2WEvex9iFmFCYiXv#anchorProgramIDL

I can go to the "Anchor Program IDL" section on Solscan at the link provided and get instructions. However, when looking at the transaction log for the NFT mint at the very bottom of the page: https://solscan.io/tx/51aicbY9JN4RiYiyq6R2F794VWaf6S44oge5uG8bokzGixvgXRPdNFHB452P1CbGhfCUkFEo9o7e54pCVRDXSChh, I found that the NFT was minted using this program and the MintV6 instruction (Log Line: "> Program log: Instruction: MintV6"), which is missing from this program's IDL.

I have been provided with the full IDL for this program, which does not match what is available on Solscan, and also does not match the IDL obtained through the use of the Anchor library in JavaScript. Link to the full IDL: https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.a170cda3e14c42909baba51ef10a3e72. If anyone knows how to obtain the full IDL, any help would be appreciated as I cannot find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Just doing some digging, looks like `ArAA6CZC123yMJLUe4uisBEgvfuw2WEvex9iFmFCYiXv` is not actually the Metaplex Candy Machine. It's a modified version maintained by Launch My NFT platform. The IDL on Solscan is updated when the program creator updates the IDL using `anchor idl`. My guess is there are some newer instructions added by LMNFT, and they haven't updated the IDL. I cannot find a repo of theirs on Github so it might be closed source.

Comment: I just found the [full IDL on Github](https://github.com/lucasig11/solaland-mint-bot/blob/main/launch-my-nft/src/lib/providers/CandyMachineProvider/implementations/LmnCandyMachineProvider/client/idl.json) and can't figure out how the person got it. So he found it somehow?

Comment: The github you link also has the source code of the program client, so I think it's quiet likely that the person who uploaded the idl also has the source code of the program. If they have that, they can just generate the idl using anchor like Amilz said.

Answer (score 0):

в 84a9c449-0d3c-40ac-b5ba-e9ed107119d2.js файле описан полный метод минта/компрессед минта их нфт, если интересно можешь покопаться там.
Либо через http запрос получать уже encode дату и просто слать транзу через `sendEncodedTransaction`

Comment: Can you please translate your answer in English for more people to understand?